# how to use alarm manager for int increase

Tags: android

I want to increase a number and show it in a TextView using AlarmManager at  a specific time of day, but it is not working. 
App is debugging and showing 0, but not increasing the int number.
Please help, here is the code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView tv;
    int a = 3;
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

        MyAlarm alarm = new MyAlarm();

        setAlarm(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
        int g = alarm.i;
        tv.setText(String.format("%d", g));
    }

    private void setAlarm(long time) {

        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        //getting the alarm manager
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        //creating a new intent specifying the broadcast receiver
        Intent i = new Intent(this, MyAlarm.class);

        //creating a pending intent using the intent
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 17);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 55);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        //setting the repeating alarm that will be fired every day
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, time, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, pi);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm is set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

broad cast is here,

```
public class MyAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {
    int i;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don;t you need a default constructor in your MyAlarm class?

Comment: How ishan? Please suggest me

Comment: A default constructor is how you create an object of your class.

Answer (score 0):

To add a default constructor, try the following in your MyAlarm class:

```
MyAlarm(){

}
```

Also add this method:

```
 public int setI(){
     i = i+1;
     return i;
 }
```

This is what it should look like now:

```
public class MyAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver{
    int i;
    MyAlarm(){
        i=0;
    }

    public int setI(){
        i = i+1;
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context,Intent intent) {
        i++;
    }
}
```

Now, call this in onCreate() and it will increment i.
You can say

```
int g = myAlarm.setI();
```

in your setAlarm() function or wherever you want to increment it.
g will now be incremented. I hope this helps!

Comment: It will increment i each time you call it. So you can call it in setAlarm()

Comment: Can you tell me how to write my alarm construct

Comment: Yes just add the code I gave in my answer in your MyAlarm class

Comment: Ok, can you specifically tell me what problem you are having?

Comment: Perhaps it is because that your method is out of class.

Comment: Which method is outside of the class?

Comment: The top two parts of code, are just what should go in your class. They should not be outside. So the final code should look like the last part.

Comment: setA it was outside of method not class.

Comment: If you have time,I want to get you personally.

Comment: I am sorry, we will communicate through these comments. But setAlarm should be outside of `onCreate`. I am a bit busy now, but I will give you a more in-depth answer once I return. In the meantime, please state all the problems you are receiving. What input you are giving, what output you are getting, and the output you expect. Thanks.

Comment: Website warned me to avoid more comments.

Comment: Ok. Maybe we can create a private Stack Overflow chat? I will look into this later. Thanks for your patience.